# How to save data from listview radiobutton to SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I want to create an app that used to take attendance. But I can't save the data that comes from the listview radio button to SQLite DB. I already did the front side. I need help at databasehelper.java class function to save on DB table.

I want to save all listview's radio button result when click save button. I got the name list from SQLite using .java class extends BaseAdapter. finally I need to store attendance radio button result and date to TABLE_ATTENDANCE.

i already got name list from sqlite DB. then i want to save attendance radio button for each name on listview. i done front part on activity_take_attendance.xml and take_att.xml files.

this is activity_take_attendance.xml
    `

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/attlv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="554dp">
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnstore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Store" />`
```

and take_att.xml is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="attendance"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/attendance"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioAttendance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/attendance">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/present"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Present"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/absent"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Absent" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/late"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:text="Late" />
    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

this is Take_Attendance.java class code.

```
btnStore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectedId = radioAttendance.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            String attendance = (String) radioButton.getText();

            databaseHelper.addAttendance(attendance, etdate.getText().toString());
            etname.setText("");
            etdate.setText("Date");
            radioAttendance.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  attendance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast.makeText(Take_Attendance.this, "Stored Successfullyyy!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and database helper.java class

```
public long addAttendance(String date, String attendance) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Creating content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    values.put(KEY_ATTENDANCE, attendance);

    long insert = db.insert(TABLE_ATTENDANCE, null, values);

    return insert;
}
```

i know above methods can't save array of list data. but i need function to save all radiobutton result for each name on list when click store button.

Answer (score 0):

try his :

```
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
           {
               radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
               String attendance = (String) radioButton.getText().toString();
              databaseHelper.addAttendance(attendance, etdate.getText().toString());
              etname.setText("");
              etdate.setText("Date");

           }
       }
       );
.
.
.
```